# Shuffling Music with OMXplayer on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python-3

So here I have created a loop that lists off each file in a folder and plays it using this python code:

```
        global shuffleVar
        listOfFiles = os.listdir('/home/pi/mysounds/')  
        pattern = "*.mp3"  
        for entry in listOfFiles:  
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(entry, pattern):
                print (entry)
                os.system('killall omxplayer.bin')
                shuffleVar = "omxplayer -o local -I --vol 0 /home/pi/mysounds/" + (entry) + " &"
                os.system(shuffleVar)
```

To break this down listOfFiles shows the directory of the music that needs tobe shuffled, pattern searches for only mp3 files, and the loop goes through each file and then makes a string to run omxplayer which is executed in os.system.
Now before going to the next song i want to be able to have keyboard and mouse inputs to either skip ahead or turn up or down volume. For this i want to use the following loop

```
                #track keyboard and mouse
                x_max = 2180 #defines largest position mouse can go (19th LED)
                x_min = 0 #defines smallest position mouse can go (9th LED)
                y_max = 2180
                y_min = 0

                async def print_events(device):
                    async for event in device.async_read_loop():
                        if event.type == ecodes.EV_KEY: #if the event is a button click
                            c = categorize(event)
                            if c.keystate == c.key_down: #only reading key for down press not up
                                print(c.keycode)
                                if ("KEY_RIGHT" in c.keycode):
                                    return

                if (globals()['correct_event'] == 1):
                    print("event determination is 1")
                    for device in keyboardEvent, mouseEvent:
                        asyncio.ensure_future(print_events(device))
                if (globals()['correct_event'] == 2):
                    print("event determination is 2")
                    asyncio.ensure_future(print_events(keyboardEvent))
                loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
                loop.run_forever()
```

now here if i press KEY_RIGHT i want to exit the listening to keyboard and mouse loop and have the for loop go to the next song. I have return after it but im not sure where i will return to. What do i do to exit the track keyboard and mouse loop and have the next for loop run through?

Comment: Might be easier to answer if you post your complete code. You might find the omxplayer wrapper easier to use https://python-omxplayer-wrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: if i use that how can i say if KEY_RIGHT play the next song?

Comment: You still need to detect your key press as you are doing.

Comment: @CoderMike Just at a first glance: the link you have given for omxplayer-wrapper installs with `pip` but uses `python3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly not a permanent change but by creating a separate file to be called i can control the keyboard when a song is playing, and to exit the async loop i use loop.stop(). This would work in my main code which has another async loop in it else where but i always get an error saying process terminated but pending! Here is my code that works!

```
import os
import fnmatch #used to list shuffle play files
import sys, termios, tty, time, serial #imports all required items
import serial.tools.list_ports
import evdev
import asyncio
from evdev import ecodes, categorize, KeyEvent, InputDevice

while (1 == 1): #this will be set to a click or esc exit inside the loop to end shuffle
    #this will list all files into an array
    global shuffleVar
    listOfFiles = os.listdir('/home/pi/mysounds/')  
    pattern = "*.mp3"  
    print(listOfFiles)
    for entry in listOfFiles:  
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(entry, pattern):
        print (entry)
        os.system('killall omxplayer.bin')
        shuffleVar = "omxplayer -o local -I --vol 0 /home/pi/mysounds/" + (entry) + " &"
        os.system(shuffleVar)

        #track keyboard and mouse
        x_max = 2180 #defines largest position mouse can go (19th LED)
        x_min = 0 #defines smallest position mouse can go (9th LED)
        y_max = 2180
        y_min = 0
        keyboardEvent = evdev.InputDevice('/dev/input/event0') #setting keyboard to USB port
        mouseEvent = evdev.InputDevice('/dev/input/event1') #setting mouse to USB port

        async def print_events2(device):
            async for event in device.async_read_loop():
                if event.type == ecodes.EV_KEY: #if the event is a button click
                    c = categorize(event)
                    if c.keystate == c.key_down: #only reading key for down press not up
                        print(c.keycode)
                        if ("KEY_RIGHT" in c.keycode):
                            print("next song")
                            loop.stop()

            for device in globals()['keyboardEvent'], globals()['mouseEvent']:
                asyncio.ensure_future(print_events2(device))
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_forever()
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this "quick and dirty" bash script to shuffle play audio files in a given directory on my Pi. Just do CTRL-C once to move to the next file and twice to exit the shuffle play.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /media/wd/audiovideo/audio/

while [ 1 -gt 0 ]
do
FILE=$(ls | shuf -n 1)
echo $FILE
omxplayer $FILE
done
```